# Running script on .xprofile fails to execute

Tags: kill, nohup

I'm trying to run a login script executing a desktop audio visualizer (`glava`) on `.xprofile` but I am running to a few problems:

First of all the script (`on ~/.local/bin/glav`):

```
#! /bin/sh
nohup glava --desktop &
kill -INT $!
```

`.xprofile` (on `~/.`):

```
#! /bin/sh
setxkbmap -option numpad:microsoft &
glav &
```

The problem:

Running `glava --desktop` on its own causes it to "run on terminal", i.e. I can't close the terminal or the program stops. It also prints fps every second,
running it with `nohup` causes it to stay on terminal like it wants to print something but <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or closing the terminal **does not** stop the program, which is the desirable outcome, so I decided to add `kill -INT $!` to the script but the script doesn't work when called from `.xprofile` at all, only when called from terminal.